# Table content alignment to left/right using tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I had tried several methods, but still unable to get the correct alignment. 
I want the first column to left hand side, then others toward right hand side.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\itshape} % optional
\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e} 
\usepackage{threeparttable} 
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering

 \begin{tablenotes}
\centering
\small
\item Dependent Variable: Testing1234 
\end{tablenotes}
\begin{threeparttable} 
%\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=2\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
%\newcolumntype{W}{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash\hsize=0.75\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
%\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Y*{3}{W}@{}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xlllll}
    \toprule
     \small {\textbf{Source}}
     & \small {\textbf{Type III Sum of Squares}} 
     & \small {\textbf{df}}
     & \small {\textbf{Mean Square}}
     & \small {\textbf{F}}
     & \small {\textbf{Sig.}}\\
     \midrule
    Corrected Model & 14573.300\tnote{a} & 3 & 4857.767 & 40.297 & .000 \\
    Testing1234 & 214036.900 & 1 & 214036.900 & 1775.503 & .000\\
    Testing1234 & .100 & 1 & .100 & .001 & .977\\
    Testing1234Testing1234 & 14137.600 & 1 & 14137.600 & 117.276 & .000\\
    Testing1234Testing1234Testing1234 & 435.600 & 1 & 435.600 & 3.613 & .065 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\footnotesize 
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a]Testing1234Testing1234Testing1234 % the footnote itself 
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\caption{Testing1234
    \label{tab:test123} }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I had tired:

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=2\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{W}{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash\hsize=0.75\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Y*{3}{W}@{}}
```

not working

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xlllll}
```

not working too

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xrrrrr}
```

Getting more confused.

Comment: Since you have an `l` column, as first column, and a very long word, this it is set on one line giving a very wide column, which overwrite the other cells. You have to set first column as an p-column, i.e. `X` or something similar. Then you must allow hyphenation by using `\RaggedRight` and `babel` and set explicit hyphenation points using `\-`. The word `Testing1234Testing1234Testing1234` is unknown for LaTeX and `babel` , so they do not know how to hyphenate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xrrrrr}`  you can get the desired result. I have also used the `\thead` command to replace repeated `\small` and `\textbf` commands and inserted manual linebreaks in the column headers of the second and fourth column:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\itshape} % optional
\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e} 

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} 
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\small
Dependent Variable: Testing1234 
\begin{threeparttable} 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xrrrrr}
    \toprule
     \thead{Source}
     & \thead{Type III\\ Sum of\\ Squares} 
     & \thead{df}
     & \thead{Mean\\ Square}
     & \thead{F}
     & \thead{Sig.}\\
     \midrule
    Corrected Model & 14573.300\tnote{a} & 3 & 4857.767 & 40.297 & .000 \\
    Testing1234 & 214036.900 & 1 & 214036.900 & 1775.503 & .000\\
    Testing1234 & .100 & 1 & .100 & .001 & .977\\
    Testing 1234Tes ting1234 & 14137.600 & 1 & 14137.600 & 117.276 & .000\\
    Testing 1234Test ing12 34Te ting1234 & 435.600 & 1 & 435.600 & 3.613 & .065 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\footnotesize 
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a]Testing1234Testing1234Testing1234 % the footnote itself 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\caption{Testing1234\label{tab:test123}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. I am very confused. `\begin{tabularx}{widthi}{preamblei}` What is the `{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xrrrrr}` and `{1\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xrrrrr}`in `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xrrrrr}` means?

Especially the `>` sign. raggedright means Left justified

Comment: @aan: An `X` type column (column type of the first column) is exactly as wide as it is needed to make the whole table as wide as the spwcified width (textwidth in your case). The contents of the `X` type column are usually justifiied. With small amounts of text and narrow `X` type columns this will lead to quite large blanks spaces between words. Therefore, and because you requested left alignment in your question, I have used `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X` in order to make the contents of the `X` type column left aligned.

Comment: To sum it up: `>{.....}` basically contains the code that is added before the contents of every cell in the respective row. You can use this to alter the horizontal alignment or print all contents of a column in bold,...

Comment: thanks. where did I define `textwidth`? I cannot find this information? In 'main.tex`?

Comment: In the set of `{}` immediately after `\begin{tabularx}`(See `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{....}`)

Comment: thanks. What is the different between `{1\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xrrrrr}` and `{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xrrrrr}`?
the `1` meaning as in textwidth.

Comment: Where was this used?

Comment: in here `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xrrrrr}`

Comment: Yes,  I understand, but I can't find it in either the question or the answers.

Comment: is there any other method to make the first box `Source` move to the right and reminding others the same?

Comment: @aan: Please see if `\thead[r]{Source}` gives you the desired result. If this does not what you wanted to achieve, please clarify the desired output.

Comment: thanks. It works. Brillant!

Answer (score 4):

You can use also `tabulary` instead of `tabularx` because this environment have L,C, R, and J columns.

But instead of R column for numbers, why not the S column of `siunitx`?

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary,siunitx,lipsum} 
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}LS[table-format=6.3]
cS[table-format=6.3]S[table-format=4.3]c@{}}\toprule
          & {Type III Sum} &       & {Mean}   &        &          \\
Source    & {of Squares}   & {df}  & {Square} & {F}    & {Sig.}   \\\midrule
Corrected Model & 14573.300$^a$ & 3 & 4857.767 & 40.297 & .000 \\
Testing1234 & 214036.900 & 1 & 214036.900 & 1775.503 & .000\\
Testing1234 & .100 & 1 & .100 & .001 & .977\\
Testing1234Testing1234 & 14137.600 & 1 & 14137.600 & 117.276 & .000\\
Testing1234Testing1234\-Testing1234 & 435.600 & 1 & 435.600 & 3.613 & .065 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
$^a$ \footnotesize Testing1234Testing1234Testing1234
\end{table}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\end{document}
```

`tabularx` is to table of a fixed width, with at least one X column of equal width (but a, ta take the make unequal columns with any justito adapt to right-justified text (R columns) Lef width to adapt to the cell contest try to make columns with unequal withat try to take the best width

Comment: thanks. Actually I am very confused when to use `tabular` and `tabularx`. Could you give a simple explanation on this? The Package tabularx - CTAN documentation (https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx?lang=en) is very hard to understand and follow.

Comment: @aan (1) `tabularx` are tables of fixed width, where each X column is expanded equally, and wrapped as needed. (2) `tabulary` is to make tables of a maximum (not fixed) width, where text is wrapped as needed at different widths in L,R,C and J columns. (2) `siunitx`  allow  S columns centered at the decimal points (4) 
 `tabular` is the basic LaTeX table that cannot wrap the text  in  `l`,`r` and `c` columns and so you cannot fix the table width, except using `p` columns were you set the width manually  (e.g. `p{3cm}`, but not the whole width, that is set by the cell contents.